# PHP multidimensional array to html table

Tags: php, html

I have an multidimensional array which I'm trying to output as a table,
here is my array;

```
$marksarray=     
array(3) {
      [0]=>
      array(2) {
        [0]=>
        string(1) "8"
        [1]=>
        string(1) "0"
      }
      [1]=>
      array(2) {
        [0]=>
        string(1) "9"
        [1]=>
        string(1) "1"
      }
      [2]=>
      array(2) {
        [0]=>
        string(2) "13"
        [1]=>
        string(1) "2"
      }
    }
```

So far I have my code like this;

```
echo "<table><tr><td>Question</td><td>Rating</td></tr>";
     foreach ($marksarray as $mks){
         foreach ($mks as $qid=>$rate){
            echo "<tr><td>".$qid."</td><td>".$rate."</td></tr>";
          }
    }
echo "</table></div>";
```

But my output is;
[image]

What is that i'm doing wrong?

Comment: What's the expected result ?

Comment: I need to pimply output the qid against the rating; Such as, 8 =>0, 9=>1, 13=>2

Comment: the array I put here is the output of var_dump

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You've got one too many `foreach`'s going on there. Try this instead:

```php
echo "<table><tr><td>Question</td><td>Rating</td></tr>";
     foreach ($marksarray as $mks){
        echo "<tr><td>".$mks[0]."</td><td>".$mks[1]."</td></tr>";
    }
echo "</table></div>";
```

For future reference, it makes your code far easier to understand if you use an array of associative arrays with meaningful keys. e.g.

```php
$marksarray = array(
    array('qid' => 8, 'rating' => 0), 
    array('qid' => 9, 'rating' => 1), 
    array('qid' => 13, 'rating' => 2)
);
```

Then your loop would look like this:

```
foreach ($marksarray as $mark){
    echo "<tr><td>".$mark['qid']."</td><td>".$mark['rating']."</td></tr>";
}
```

Better still, you should use MVC (Model, View, Controller) and pass this data into a view...but that's another subject entirely.

Answer (score 1):

When you `echo` your array, you are outputting the `key` rather than the actual values.  Hence why you're getting '0' and '1's in your first column.

If you are stuck with the array layout that you currently have, you want the following code:

```
echo "<table><tr><td>Question</td><td>Rating</td></tr>";
     foreach ($marksarray as $mks){
        echo "<tr><td>".$mks[0]."</td><td>".$mks[1]."</td></tr>";
     }
echo "</table></div>";
```

... so that you are making use of the key values to pull out the matching values that you want to show.

If you're not stuck with the array structure that you have now, you'd have to structure your array like so, to make use of the `key` and `pair` values:

```
$marksarray = array(
    "8" => 0,
    "9" => 1,
    "13" => 2,
);
```

and use the code:

```
echo "<table><tr><td>Question</td><td>Rating</td></tr>";
     foreach ($marksarray as $qid => $rate){

        echo "<tr><td>".$qid."</td><td>".$rate."</td></tr>";

     }
echo "</table></div>";
```

... this way you are making clear reference to your `key` and `pair` values within your code.

Answer (score 0):

change the echo line to

```
   echo "<tr><td>".$rate[0]."</td><td>".$rate[1]."</td></tr>";
```

Is it working?

Answer (score 0):

This is outputting correctly, and your loops look fine. What I think you mean to do in your array is something like:

```
$marksarray = array(
    "8" => "0",
    "9" => "1",
    "13" => "2"
);
```

Then change your loop to:

```
echo "<table><tr><td>Question</td><td>Rating</td></tr>";
         foreach ($marksarray as $qid=>$rate){
            echo "<tr><td>".$qid."</td><td>".$rate."</td></tr>";
          }
echo "</table></div>";
```

Answer (score 0):

I know this is a little old, but I believe this code will do exactly what you want with the existing array.

```
echo "<table><tr><td>Question</td><td>Rating</td></tr>";
 foreach ($marksarray as $mks){
     echo "<tr>";
     foreach ($mks as $qid=>$rate){
        echo "<td>".$rate."</td>";
      }
      echo "</tr>";
}
```

`echo "</table></div>";`

Is there any reason not to do it this way?

Answer (score 0):

try using this code

```
function printmarraytable($data){
                            echo "<table>";
                            foreach($data as $key=>$value){
                                echo "<tr><td>".$key."</td>";
                                if(is_array($value) || is_object($value)){
                                    echo "<td>".printmarraytable($value)."     </td>";
                                }else{
                                    echo "<td>".$value."</td></tr>";
                                }
                            }
                            echo "</table>";
                          }
                          printmarraytable($req);
```