# PHP Array and how to display it with this order of array

Tags: php, arrays

I have an array that is the one below.

I need to be able to display it like a table with first columns on top being Agent Names. The columns on the left displaying dates, and sums in the records where they intersect. I understand how to step through and add HTML in a For Each.. However I am having trouble with the sorting to have it appear correct.. Something like the table below:

--------------1-23-2018---------------1-24-2018---------------------

Daniel ---$1,995.00 ----------------$1,459.00

Gail ------$1,695.00 ----------------$3,845.00

---

I understand how to step through

Please Help. I am doing all this in PHP.

```
Array (
[2018-01-23] => Array
    (
        [0] => Array
            (
                [0] => Daniel
                [Agent] => Daniel
                [1] => 2018-01-23
                [Deal_Date] => 2018-01-23
                [2] => 1995.00
                [Total] => 1995.00
            )

        [1] => Array
            (
                [0] => Gail
                [Agent] => Gail
                [1] => 2018-01-23
                [Deal_Date] => 2018-01-23
                [2] => 1695.00
                [Total] => 1695.00
            )

        [2] => Array
            (
                [0] => Joe
                [Agent] => Joe
                [1] => 2018-01-23
                [Deal_Date] => 2018-01-23
                [2] => 395.00
                [Total] => 395.00
            )

        [3] => Array
            (
                [0] => Judy
                [Agent] => Judy
                [1] => 2018-01-23
                [Deal_Date] => 2018-01-23
                [2] => 1795.00
                [Total] => 1795.00
            )

        [4] => Array
            (
                [0] => Justin
                [Agent] => Justin
                [1] => 2018-01-23
                [Deal_Date] => 2018-01-23
                [2] => 2390.00
                [Total] => 2390.00
            )

        [5] => Array
            (
                [0] => Kevin
                [Agent] => Kevin
                [1] => 2018-01-23
                [Deal_Date] => 2018-01-23
                [2] => 1800.00
                [Total] => 1800.00
            )

        [6] => Array
            (
                [0] => Sky
                [Agent] => Sky
                [1] => 2018-01-23
                [Deal_Date] => 2018-01-23
                [2] => 795.00
                [Total] => 795.00
            )

        [7] => Array
            (
                [0] => Tony
                [Agent] => Tony
                [1] => 2018-01-23
                [Deal_Date] => 2018-01-23
                [2] => 1695.00
                [Total] => 1695.00
            )

    )

[2018-01-25] => Array
    (
        [0] => Array
            (
                [0] => Daniel
                [Agent] => Daniel
                [1] => 2018-01-25
                [Deal_Date] => 2018-01-25
                [2] => 4590.00
                [Total] => 4590.00
            )

        [1] => Array
            (
                [0] => Gail
                [Agent] => Gail
                [1] => 2018-01-25
                [Deal_Date] => 2018-01-25
                [2] => 3845.00
                [Total] => 3845.00
            )

        [2] => Array
            (
                [0] => Joe
                [Agent] => Joe
                [1] => 2018-01-25
                [Deal_Date] => 2018-01-25
                [2] => 495.00
                [Total] => 495.00
            )

        [3] => Array
            (
                [0] => Justin
                [Agent] => Justin
                [1] => 2018-01-25
                [Deal_Date] => 2018-01-25
                [2] => 945.00
                [Total] => 945.00
            )

        [4] => Array
            (
                [0] => Kevin
                [Agent] => Kevin
                [1] => 2018-01-25
                [Deal_Date] => 2018-01-25
                [2] => 1995.00
                [Total] => 1995.00
            )

        [5] => Array
            (
                [0] => Kyle
                [Agent] => Kyle
                [1] => 2018-01-25
                [Deal_Date] => 2018-01-25
                [2] => 1790.00
                [Total] => 1790.00
            )

        [6] => Array
            (
                [0] => Lisa
                [Agent] => Lisa
                [1] => 2018-01-25
                [Deal_Date] => 2018-01-25
                [2] => 1995.00
                [Total] => 1995.00
            )

        [7] => Array
            (
                [0] => Sam
                [Agent] => Sam
                [1] => 2018-01-25
                [Deal_Date] => 2018-01-25
                [2] => 2990.00
                [Total] => 2990.00
            )

        [8] => Array
            (
                [0] => Sky
                [Agent] => Sky
                [1] => 2018-01-25
                [Deal_Date] => 2018-01-25
                [2] => 995.00
                [Total] => 995.00
            )

        [9] => Array
            (
                [0] => Tony
                [Agent] => Tony
                [1] => 2018-01-25
                [Deal_Date] => 2018-01-25
                [2] => 995.00
                [Total] => 995.00
            )
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [PHP multidimensional array to html table](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13767211/php-multidimensional-array-to-html-table)

Comment: Try something like this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13767211/php-multidimensional-array-to-html-table & Moving forward please provide a [mcve] of what you've tried on your own to solve this problem.

Comment: We could probably do a great job of helping you, starting from the query, if you provide an sqlfiddle link.  It looks like your results set is `_array` but only needs to be `_assoc`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you are trying to create is a [Pivot table](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pivot_table). In general, it is not a simple task to do (that is one of the killer features of spreadsheets (i.e. Excel)), but in your particular case you can do the following:

```
// Flatten array, maybe redundant if you get data in appropriate format.
$flatten = array_reduce($array, 'array_merge', []);

// Store all unique dates in the index lookup table (j).
$dates = array_flip(array_values(array_unique(array_column($flatten, 'Deal_Date'))));
// Store all unique names in the index lookup table (i).
$names = array_flip(array_values(array_unique(array_column($flatten, 'Agent'))));

$totals = array_reduce(
    $flatten,
    function ($totals, $item) use ($names, $dates) {
        $i = $names[$item['Agent']];
        $j = $dates[$item['Deal_Date']];
        $totals[$i][$j] += $item['Total'];

        return $totals;
    },
    // Prefil table with zeros.
    array_fill(0, count($names), array_fill(0, count($dates), 0))
);

// Displaying part:
// Merge all the raws and cols together (add headers).
$table = $totals;
array_unshift($table, array_flip($dates));
$names = array_flip($names);
array_unshift($names, null);
$table = array_map(function ($name, $row) {
    array_unshift($row, $name);

    return $row;
}, $names, $table);

// Calculate max widthes for better displaying:
$width = array_map(function ($column) {
    return max(array_map('strlen', $column));
}, array_map(null, ...$table));

foreach ($table as $row) {
    echo implode(' | ', array_map(function ($cell, $width) {
        return str_pad($cell, $width);
    }, $row, $width)), PHP_EOL;
}
```

This will give you a table like the following:

```
       | 2018-01-23 | 2018-01-25
Daniel | 1995       | 4590      
Gail   | 1695       | 3845      
Joe    | 395        | 495       
Judy   | 1795       | 0         
Justin | 2390       | 945       
Kevin  | 1800       | 1995      
Sky    | 795        | 995       
Tony   | 1695       | 995       
Kyle   | 0          | 1790      
Lisa   | 0          | 1995      
Sam    | 0          | 2990
```

Here is [the demo](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/9f0c7e6832625af417f632e7531ba086cc0b042f).

For a more general solution, please, consider using some dedicated library, for example, [this one](https://github.com/mhadjimichael/PHPivot).